# Rephrase pascal code to c++ so it can work as efficient as possible

Tags: c++, pascal

So I got this task where I have pascal code and I need to get out whats the result. That wouldn't be a problem because I know pascal, but I need it to run in 1 second or less with numbers up to 10^9.

```
readln(N);
counter:=0;
for i:=N-1 downto 1 do begin
    counter:= counter + 1;
    if N mod i = 0 then break;
end;
writeln(counter);
```

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    int counter = 0;
    cin>>x;
    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++){
        if (x % i == 0){
            counter = x - x / i;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<counter;
    return 0;
}
```

but it still cant quite get max score.

Comment: Please rephrase the question title and state the problem with checking for non-primality and addition.
The problem here is not with the language but the algorithm complexity. You can improve on that.

Comment: Your new title is even worse. **Your problem is not to run specific code as fast as possible, but to avoid having to run it at all.** There's nothing you can do to fix your code -- it's just the wrong approach, and you will need to start thinking differently. **Do not reimplement the original Pascal program**, you cannot win with that.

Comment: By the way, just benchmarked that. If I use SSE SIMD instructions, even your horribly bad implementation runs in under one second.

Comment: 1) I just updated my code 2)I'm running it on special server for testing this kind of code and it fails in 2/12 times

Comment: **NOOOOO** Do **not** rephrase the original code. How could you make the title even worse??

Comment: SORRY This is my first post :(

Comment: this is not about it being your first post, this is about you not trying to understand that you cannot make your approach faster. You have to think about how to implement a solution without doing any loops :/ And I've told you this four times now, mrVoid has pointed you to it and CiaPan has really offered good advice. Still you think your bad approach needs to be faster. Delete your code, start from the beginning: What number do you get in the end? What's a different way of getting the same number, without using code that looks like the original program?

Comment: The original code looks for the largest factor < N.  Most of the time your idea of looking for the smallest factor > 1 and using it to compute that largest factor, is a solid improvement (maybe not enough but big).  But what about the case that the largest factor you are looking for is `1`.  You should notice much faster that the input is prime and special case that.  (Having computed that largest factor, you seem to already be correct on how to compute the final answer from that factor.  What you must improve is computing that factor).

Comment: *sigh* your problem is still not *making your code run as efficiently as possible*, please try to understand that your code is the wrong approach. With an approach a little more elegant, you could implement it as horribly as imaginable and still be fast enough.

Comment: with the updated code, you're getting there! congrats!

Comment: I've rolled back your edit (the one that posts the solution), because that's not how StackOverflow works. If you want to share the solution to the problem, write an answer in the space provided and post it *as an answer*. It's acceptable to answer your own questions here; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restate problem:
1)  Compute F = largest proper factor of X
2)  Output X-F

Instead of directly searching for the largest proper factor, apply three trivial optimizations (maybe something more advanced will be needed, but first see if three trivial optimizations are enough).

A) Find S = smallest factor of X greater than 1.  Output X-(X/S)
B) Special case for prime
C) Special case for even

```
int largest_proper_factor(int X)
{
   if ( X % 2 == 0 ) return X/2;  // Optimize even

   // Note the add of .5 is only needed for non compliant sqrt version that
   // might return a tiny fraction less than the exact answer.
   int last = (int)(.5 + std::sqrt( (double) X )) );

   for ( int i=3; i<=last; i+=2 ) // big savings here because even was optimized earlier
   {
      if ( X % i == 0 ) return X/i;
   }
   return 1;  // special case for prime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers like 10^9 usually indicate contest problems, which need creative thinking instead of fast CPU...

See, `N mod i = 0` means `N` is divisible by `i`. So the loop counts numbers between `N` and one of its divisor (possibly plus one... Check it.) Which one — remains for you.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i got the result i wanned:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    int counter = 0;
    cin>>x;
    for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++){
        if (x % i == 0){
            counter = x - x / i;
            break;
        }
        if (x / 4 == i){
            i = x - 1;
        }
    }
    cout<<counter;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you everyone who helped me:)